# Adding many lists

Tags: c#

If I have 100 lists (eg x1 to x100), is there a better way of expressing the final line of code?

```
        var x1 = new List<int>() { 75 };
        var x2 = new List<int>() { 95, 64 };
        var x3 = new List<int>() { 17, 47, 82 };
        var x4 = new List<int>() { 18, 35, 87, 10 };
        var x5 = new List<int>() { 20, 04, 82, 47, 65 };
        var x6 = new List<int>() { 19, 01, 23, 75, 03, 34 };
        var x7 = new List<int>() { 88, 02, 77, 73, 07, 63, 67 };
        //etc..
        var listOfListOfInts = new List<List<int>>() { x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15 };
```

possibly a Dictionary and a for loop to reference all the x1..100.

Comment: Why not add them as you're creating the lists...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as `x1` etc. aren't referenced elsewhere, then write:

```
var listOfListOfInts = new List<List<int>>()
{
    new List<int>() { 75 },
    new List<int>() { 95, 64 },
    //etc.
};
```

In fact you shouldn't *need* to reference the individual variables elsewhere since `listOfListOfInts[0]` is just as good as `x1` for example.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need these to be of type `List<T>`? It looks like you're setting up preinitialized data. If you're never going to change the length of any of these "lists", you could use arrays instead; the syntax is more compact:

```
var listOfListOfInts = new[] {
    new[] { 75 },
    new[] { 95, 64 },
    new[] { 17, 47, 82 },
    new[] { 18, 35, 87, 10 },
    new[] { 20, 04, 82, 47, 65 },
    new[] { 19, 01, 23, 75, 03, 34 },
    new[] { 88, 02, 77, 73, 07, 63, 67 },
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Well now it should be `arrayOfArrayOfInts` :)

Comment: Changing to arrays is quite an assumption. Making the syntax more compact has other side-effects which may be undesirable for the OP.

Comment: @Yuck, that's why I specifically called out the circumstances where this answer would (and wouldn't) apply: "If you're never going to change the length of any of these 'lists'...". This does look like input data that's initialized and then only read, so I figured the answer might be helpful.

Comment: Good thought Joe, thanks.  This was part of my solution to http://projecteuler.net/problem=18  and in fact arrays are probably what I should refactor to.  Did this in a TDD manner, and lists just happened to be the first thing I tried :-).  Full code here (Spoiler alert!) http://www.programgood.net/2012/06/06/Euler18.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps i'm over complicating things but you could do something like

```
public interface IClass1
{
    IList<IList<int>> ListList { get; set; }
    void AddList(List<int> nList);
}

public class Class1 : IClass1
{
    public IList<IList<int>> ListList { get; set; }

    public void AddList(List<int> nList)
    {
        ListList.Add(nList);
    }
}
```

and then use it like:

```
public class Create1
{
    public Create1()
    {
        IClass1 iClass1 = new Class1();
        iClass1.AddList(new List<int>() { 75 });
    }
}
```